# php phalcon phql update

Tags: php, phalcon

I am new to phalcon framework.I would like to update data from phalcon model update method.

> $sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `col1`='1',`col2` = NULL WHERE 1";

to

```
>  $all = model::findFirst();
>                 $all->col1 = '1';
>                 $all->col2= NULL;
>                 $all->update();
```

I have no idea about for "where 1" .

Comment: What do you mean with `WHERE 1` ? are you missing a column here ? `WHERE col1 = 1` ?

Comment: I deleted it @Timothy

Answer (score 0):

Before you can update a model you need to request it from the database.
In the following example you are querying the first record where the value in column `col1` equals `123`.

```
$all = model::findFirst(['col1 = 123']);
// you can also write this like
$all = model::findFirstByCol1(123);
```

In the background Phalcon will convert the above code to a query, similar to:

> SELECT * FROM model WHERE col1 = 123 LIMIT 1;

Now that you have access to the model via `$all`, you can alter its attributes:

```
$all->col2 = null;
```

If you are done altering `$all`, you can update the values in the database:

```
$all->update(); // or $all->save();
```

Refer to the [Phalcon documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html), if you need more help on working with models.

Answer (score -1):

What is this `WHERE 1` ? You mean `WHERE id = 1` ? Then you need:

```
$all = model::findFirst(1);
$all->col1 = '1';
$all->col2= NULL;
$all->update();
```

Comment: It will select if id is your PK(primary key) in database. Passing integer value to findFirst means phalcon will look for PK - if it will find it it will get the name of this PK and find for value which you passed.

Comment: table has without primary key .

Comment: Then you need to use findFirstByCol1 or something. Or just create PR. Also phalcon as far as i know will not update anything until it has PR.